# Sound problem from classic 350 dual disc model

Tags: noise

My new classic350 dual disc model   produce tak tak sound sometime when it is running when i take clutch and dissapears when i accelerate. It happens  once or twice a day

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is this a Royal Enfield motorcycle?

Comment: If the machine is still under warranty (you say it is "new"), take it to the dealer and  let them figure it out.